# Javascript / take X days with specific pattern

Tags: javascript

I have the next in js, in order to file the date before 29 days:

```
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(d.getDate() - 29);
    console.log(d);
```

and it return:

```
Sat Nov 22 2014 07:32:22 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

I want that it will return the following:

```
11-22-14
```

there is any way to do it?

Comment: I suggest you to use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log((d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d.getDate()+'-'+d.getFullYear().toString().slice(-2));
```